# Power BI | circumvent "Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot..." when adding a calculated column to a summarized table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Again.

Sorry to bother, but currently, I'm trying to estimate the size of a call center, which of course, requires calculating some parameters for the Erlang-A distribution. At this time, I want to get the Average Time to Abandon, which, in fact, is the [median of the abandon time](https://www.callcentrehelper.com/measure-call-abandon-rate-75869.htm#averagepatience), or, the abandon time up to which the lower half the abandoned calls are abandoned.

TABLE A is the result of a SELECTCOLUMN function that yields:

TABLE A

| Call ID | date | YEAR | MONTH | WEEK OF THE YEAR | DAY OF THE WEEK | TIME BAND | SERVICE | TIME BEFORE ABANDON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asdf1 | 19-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 17 | 1 | 11 hrs | INFO | 49 |
| asdf8 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 16 hrs | INFO | 57 |
| asdf7 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 16 hrs | INFO | 85 |
| asdf5 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 08 hrs | INFO | 103 |
| asdf2 | 20-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 17 | 2 | 12 hrs | APPOINTMENT | 123 |
| asdf4 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 09 hrs | INFO | 176 |
| asdf3 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 13 hrs | HOTLINE | 224 |
| asdf6 | 26-apr-2021 | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 16 hrs | INFO | 296 |

Call ID is unique.

What I want to do is to calculate the median, for any number of "filters" combination.

For example, the GENERAL median should be 103 seconds, but, if I focus only on the calls that took place in the 16 hrs time band, the median is 85 seconds

TABLE B was created with the  SUMMARIZE function applied on TABLE A. So, from TABLE A sample, TABLE B

TABLE B

| SERVICE | YEAR | MONTH | WEEK OF THE YEAR | DAY OF THE WEEK | TIME BAND | - | fully filtered MEDIAN PATIENCE | MEDIAN PATIENCE (service only) | GENERAL MEDIAN PATIENCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INFO | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 16 | - | 85 | 85 | 103 |
| INFO | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 08 | - | 103 | 85 | 103 |
| INFO | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 09 | - | 176 | 85 | 103 |
| INFO | 2021 | 4 | 17 | 1 | 11 | - | 49 | 85 | 103 |
| APPOINTMENT | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 2 | 12 | - | 123 | 123 | 103 |
| HOTLINE | 2021 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 13 | - | 224 | 224 | 103 |

From SERVICE to TIME Band, it's the summarize part. Afterwards, it's the median(s) columns

**What I want** is to add the medians columns. However, for the fully filtered median, I'm attempting to do so with the code:

`fully median patience = CALCULATE(MEDIAN('TABLE A'[TIME BEFORE ABANDON]), FILTER('TABLE A', 'TABLE A'[SERVICE] = 'TABLE B'[SERVICE] && 'TABLE A'[YEAR] = 'TABLE B'[YEAR] && 'TABLE A'[MONTH] = 'TABLE B'[MONTH] && 'TABLE A'[DAY OF THE WEEK] = 'TABLE B'[DAY OF THE WEEK] && 'TABLE A'[TIME BAND] = 'TABLE B'[TIME BAND]))`

But I'm getting the message: `"Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns."`

Which seems weird to me, since the function countrows works just fine within a CALCULATE, and applied to a bunch of summarized columns.

As a matter of fact, I can get the median with a MEASURE, insert it in a CARD VISUAL, and I only have to add the filters to it. Or add many slicers to a dashboard page. But still, It would be better to get medians in the TABLE in order visualize many medians at the time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You result must contain some blanks that's why you are getting the error, do explicit conversion with CONVERT

```
fully median patience =
CONVERT (
    CALCULATE (
        MEDIAN ( 'TABLE A'[TIME BEFORE ABANDON] ),
        FILTER (
            'TABLE A',
            'TABLE A'[SERVICE] = 'TABLE B'[SERVICE]
                && 'TABLE A'[YEAR] = 'TABLE B'[YEAR]
                && 'TABLE A'[MONTH] = 'TABLE B'[MONTH]
                && 'TABLE A'[DAY OF THE WEEK] = 'TABLE B'[DAY OF THE WEEK]
                && 'TABLE A'[TIME BAND] = 'TABLE B'[TIME BAND]
        )
    ),
    INTEGER
)
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution was on point, though I already got around it by simply inputting the columns in a matrix visual. THANKS.